# Iterating through object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object which helds an array of owners objects.

```
 carData.Porsche[0].OwnerName;
 carData.Porsche[1].OwnerName;
 carData.Ferrari[0].OwnerName;
 carData.Ferrari[1].OwnerName;
 carData.Ferrari[2].OwnerName;
```

I would like to iterate through this data structure so I will print:

```
Porsche: OwnerName,  Porsche: OwnerName, Ferrari: OwnerName etc..
```

but I have no clue how ( I'm new to Javascript). Would appreciate some tips.

Comment: please add `carData` as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a for loop to iterate the object

```
for (let in carData) {

  let car = carData[i];
  for (let j in car) {

    console.log(car[j].OwnerName);

  }

}
```